# How can I encode and decode an image for use with the Hedera file service?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I want to store images on the [Hedera file service](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/file-service) but I have no idea on how to get started. I don't know how I should encode my image and how to decode it. The [documentation](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/file-service/get-file-contents) is extremely vague and does mention any form of data types, data structures or encoding except utf-8.

Please note that I have very little experience with file and data encoding overall.

Comment: 1) The documentation doesn't say because the file service is completely agnostic with respect to what blob of bytes you stick in it.  Images, PDFs, music, Windows 98 executable files, whatever.  You put your bytes in, you get your bytes out.  Watch for the limit on initial file size though: It's 1Kb.  You put longer files into the Hedera file service by appending chunks to it in subsequent transactions.

Comment: 2) It's possible - maybe even likely - that you don't actually want to stick your _file_ (if its large, like an image) into the file service. Many - even most - use cases use the more typical Web3 pattern of putting a filehash + metadata in there and putting the file _contents_ somewhere else, like IPFS.  And if you're doing _that_ you may not even need the file service, it's possible the consensus service will suffice.  But it of course depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use byte arrays, this is the standard way.